# read_table() from readr package in R

Tags: r, readr

I am currently attempting to use `read_table()` function from the readr package on a few large data files. I only want the second column so I set all the other columns NULL with this argument in the function:

```
col_types = c(paste("_", "c", paste(rep("_", 20000), sep = "", collapse = ""), sep = "", collapse  = ""))
```

**EDIT:** There should be an underdash between the 1st and 3rd pair of closed quotes in the code above.

However, read_table seems to insist on reading in the entire data file (And using up excessive memory and causing a crash) instead of just reading in column 2.

With `read.table()`, I have tried a similar argument: `colClasses = c("NULL", "character", rep("NULL", 20000)` which works perfectly without taking up excess memory but I would like to use `read_table` since it is supposedly faster. Any ideas on why `read_table` is taking up so much memory even though I am including an argument to only keep one column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to read the second column of a large data file, you can also use the `fread` function from the [`data.table` package](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). The `fread` function was also developed for (very) fast file reading.

`fread` has a `select` argument with which you can determine which columns to load. In your case it would be something like:

```
dt <- fread("name_of_file.csv", select=2)
```

This selects only the second column. You can also give it a vector of columns:

```
dt <- fread("name_of_file.csv", select=c(2,5,10))
```

or a vector of column names:

```
dt <- fread("name_of_file.csv", select=c("id","time"))
```

Comment: I would definitely prefer the fread() function but unfortunately this function results in an error message for me: embedded nul in string  'àáõ“Ô\003\0IÏøá4ÔZM2Ì'

Comment: @user2205537 could you give the full error message (including the command you are using)?

Comment: Nevermind! Problem solved! It was the .gz compressed file format being incompatible with fread(). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2205537 That's indeed not possible yet. However, such a [feature will be incorporated in the future](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/717).